# Woocommerce mini cart cannot show properly on my custom theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am making a wordpress theme with integrated woocommerce and have problem like two buttons (details & checkout) cannot show with properly in mini cart layout after added a product or more to cart on [shop page](http://dev.galerigadget.com/shop/) like screenshot below:
[image: mini cart on shop page]

After I navigated to [home page](http://dev.galerigadget.com/) it will show without any problem for mini cart below:
[image: mini cart on home page]

**Header.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package testing
 */
global $woocommerce;
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="container">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'gg' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation2" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="top-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Top Menu', 'gg' ); ?></button>

<ul class="mini-cart">

<li> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('View your shopping cart'); ?>" class="cart-parent"> 

<div class="bubblex">
               <div class="inside">
                 <div class="inside-text">
<?php 

echo sprintf(_n('%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);

?></div>
      </div>
    </div>

<i class="cart_control">::before</i></a> 
<?php

echo '<ul class="cart_list">';

echo '<li class="cart-title"><b>Isi Keranjang:</b></li>';

if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents)>0) : foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) :

$_product = $cart_item['data'];

if ($_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity']>0) :

echo '<li class="cart_list_product"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( intval( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) ) . '">';

/* echo $_product->get_image(); */

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_widget_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $_product ) . '</a>';

if($_product instanceof woocommerce_product_variation && is_array($cart_item['variation'])) :

echo woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $cart_item['variation'] );

endif;

echo '<span class="quantity">' . $cart_item['quantity'] . ' &times; ' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . '</span></li>';

endif;

endforeach;

else: echo '<li class="empty">' . __( 'Keranjang kosong') . '</li>'; endif;

if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) > 0 ) :

echo '<li class="total">';

echo  '<span class="amount2">Total</span>' . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() . '</li>';

echo '<p class="buttons"><a href="' . esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ) . '" class="button">Detail</a> <a href="' . esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="button checkout">Checkout</a></p>';

endif;

echo '</ul>';

?>

</li> </ul>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top', 'menu_id' => 'top-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'gg' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div><!-- #site-wrapper -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

**Style.css**

```
.main-navigation2 .cart_control {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 19px;
    width: 30px;
    float: right;
    background: url('img/icons/set_icons/cart-grey.png') center no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    /* line-height: 9999em; */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-navigation2 .cart_wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    position:  absolute;
    width: 300px;
    right: -2px;
    background-color: #494949;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-navigation2  .mini-cart .sf-sub-indicator {
  display: none!important;
}
.main-navigation2  .mini-cart > li {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 19% 29%;
}
.main-navigation2 .mini-cart > li ul.cart_list {
  display: none!important;
  visibility: hidden!important;
}
.main-navigation2  .mini-cart > li:hover {
   padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   /* line-height: 42px; */
   color: #000;
   font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main-navigation2  .mini-cart a.cart-parent {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 47px;
  float: right;
  background: url('img/icons/set_icons/cart-grey.png') center no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
  /* line-height: 0em; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  z-index: 1000;
}
.main-navigation2 .mini-cart a.cart-parent:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-navigation2 .mini-cart a.cart-parent span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1;
}
.main-navigation2 .mini-cart a.cart-parent mark {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative; 
}

.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart {
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 61px 0 0;
    width: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li:hover {
    position: static;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li:hover ul.cart_list {
    right: 244px;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li {
    text-align: right;
    width: auto;/* The cart contents drop down */
  }
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li:hover ul.cart_list {
    display: block!important;
    visibility: visible!important;
  }
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list {
   text-align: left;
   position: absolute;
   width: 283px;
   right: -2px;
   background-color: #ff0000;
   z-index: 1000;
   padding: 16px 6px;
   color: #000;/* The totals *//* The buttons */
   margin: -13px 7px 0px 0px;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.empty {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li {
    margin: 0px 18px 0px 18px;
    padding: 0 0 6px 9px;
    float: none;
    /* height: 80px; */
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1.1;
    background: #fff;
    /* -webkit-border-radius: 10px; */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart-title {
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart-title h3 {
    padding: 6px 0 6px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #050505;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    clear: left;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product img {
    float: right;
    padding: .27em;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.136em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.136em;
    border-radius: 0.136em;
    margin: 0 0 .27em .27em;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product a {
    border: 0;
    margin: -5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #050505; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    background: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: normal;
    width: auto;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product a:hover {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product dl.variation {
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=@opacity * 100);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.cart_list_product dl.variation dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    font-weight: 700;
}
 .main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list li.total {
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px;
    margin: 20px 16px 6px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    border-bottom: none;
    /* -webkit-border-radius: 10px; */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); */
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 }
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons {
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px!important;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0!important;
}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons .button {
    border-top: 1px solid #451c08;
    background: #573220;
    background: 
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#de591b), to(#573220));
    background: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #de591b, #573220);
    background: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #de591b, #573220);
    background: 
    -ms-linear-gradient(top, #de591b, #573220);
    background: 
    -o-linear-gradient(top, #de591b, #573220);
    padding: 0px 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: -2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 0 0 -37px 16px;
}

.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons .button.checkout {
    margin: 0 0 0 160px;

}
.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons .button:hover {
   border-top-color: #853718;
   background: #853718;
   color: #ccc;
}

.main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons .button:active {
   border-top-color: #573220;
   background: #573220;
}

span.amount2 {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 30px 0 8px;
    color: #000;
}
```

So how I can fix it to make mini cart layout will show with properly for all pages on my custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

try this css

> .main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons{ position:
>   relative } .main-navigation2 ul.mini-cart li ul.cart_list p.buttons
>   .button{ position: absolute: -4px; }

Comment: still no luck. Also what do you mean from { position: absolute: -4px; }?

Comment: give positin relative to wrapper ( ul.cart_list p.buttons )  and give position absolute and left:-4px;  to ( ul.cart_list p.buttons .button ) its shd work

Comment: line number 1164  ( position: relative )
line number 1170 (position: absolute; left: -4px; )